# CS50 Pset4 Filter (less comfortable) blur function Algorithmic Issue

Tags: c, algorithm, cs50, bmp

[info about this task](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/4/filter/less/)

when I try to implement blur function, It works fine to me on a picture, but check50 (cs50 test program) gives warning for my outputs.

Here is my code

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    float average_red = 0;
    float average_green = 0;
    float average_blue = 0;
    float count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            // reset values 
            average_red = 0;
            average_blue = 0;
            average_green = 0;
            count = 0;

            // look for around a pixel 3x3 box
            // column
            for (int k = i - 1; k < i + 2; k++)
            {
                // row
                for (int l = j - 1; l < j + 2; l++)
                {
                    // if pixel on the top
                    if (k == -1)
                    {
                        // it skips a column because it is out of the border
                        break;
                    }

                    // if pixel is on the left side
                    if (l == -1)
                    {
                        // skips a row otherwise it is out of the border
                        continue;
                    }

                    // if pixel passes the bottom
                    if (k >= height)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    // if pixels passes the right side
                    if (l >= width)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    
                    // everything else
                    else
                    {
                        average_red += image[k][l].rgbtRed;
                        average_green += image[k][l].rgbtGreen;
                        average_blue += image[k][l].rgbtBlue;
                        count++;
                    }
                }   
            }

            average_red /= count;
            average_green /= count;
            average_blue /= count;
            image[i][j].rgbtRed  = round(average_red);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(average_green);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(average_blue);

        }
    }
    return;
}
```

[expected output vs my output is here](https://submit.cs50.io/check50/c415409b42976f75edbd7e7a246ea4680cc9138a) (blur functions output very down bellow)

It is working fine on the corner but other pixel values are very close to correct output, but not the same.
Any help appreciated

Comment: the "info about this task" fails to mention the detail that each line of the pixel map must contain bytes such that the total byte count is a multiple of 4

Comment: OT: regarding statements like: `float average_red = 0;`  This is trying to assign a `int` literal into a `float` variable.  When you compiler with the warnings enabled, this will result in a compiler warning statement.  Suggest:  `float average_red = 0.0f;`  Notice the `.` and the trailing `f` which makes the literal a `float`

Comment: The posted code does not compile! amongst other problems, it is calling the function: `round()` but is missing the needed header file: `math.h`

Comment: the `Makefile` is missing the library reference `-lm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem, thanks for helps anyway

problem in was my sum calculation. it keeps result in image[i][j] and than again uses this value again.
I copy image values to a new value and use on this. Here is my code

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // copy original value to a new value to keep changing values
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }

    float average_red = 0.0f;
    float average_green = 0.0f;
    float average_blue = 0.0f;
    float count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            // reset values 
            average_red = 0.0f;
            average_blue = 0.0f;
            average_green = 0.0f;
            count = 0;

            // look for around a pixel 3x3 box
            // column
            for (int k = i - 1; k < i + 2; k++)
            {
                // row
                for (int l = j - 1; l < j + 2; l++)
                {
                    // if pixel on the top
                    if (k == -1)
                    {
                        // it skips a column because it is out of the border
                        break;
                    }

                    // if pixel is on the left side
                    else if (l == -1)
                    {
                        // skips a row otherwise it is out of the border
                        continue;
                    }

                    // if pixel passes the bottom
                    else if (k >= height)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    // if pixels passes the right side
                    else if (l >= width)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    
                    // everything else
                    else
                    {
                        average_red += copy[k][l].rgbtRed;
                        average_green += copy[k][l].rgbtGreen;
                        average_blue += copy[k][l].rgbtBlue;
                        count++;
                    }
                }   
            }

            average_red /= count;
            average_green /= count;
            average_blue /= count;
            image[i][j].rgbtRed  = round(average_red);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(average_green);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(average_blue);

        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code needs to take several factors into consideration. Suggest:

if the resulting row number is <0 or >(height-1) then don't calc that pixel

if the resulting column number is <0 or >(width-1) then don't calc that pixel

Therefore, for each of the surrounding 8 pixels, apply the two above criteria.